# Posting the same content on Stack Overflow and Medium.com

Tags: discussion

I just opened an account on Medium.com.

I'm thinking about taking canonical questions and/or answers I write, or have already written, for Stack Exchange sites and posting them on Medium.

Basically, I would use content that I have authored here, modify it for presentation as an essay, and post it there. Titles may be identical in both places.

Will these (mostly) duplicate postings run afoul of any written or unwritten rules or conventions here at Stack Exchange? I did review the Stack copyright license ([cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) and see no problems there. Any other thoughts or problems come to mind? Thanks.

Comment: I would link to the original content and disclose your affiliation with the creation of said content just to avoid anyone taking issue with it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When you post on Stack Overflow your content is licensed under [CC by-SA](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). This means that *anyone* can remix your content for any reason as long as they give [proper attribution to you](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/). However, the license is "non-exclusive", which means that you, as the owner of the content, can also license your content under [whatever non-exclusive license](https://medium.com/policy/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f) Medium uses, without *needing* to properly attribute yourself. (This works the same both ways, whether you publish on Stack Overflow or Medium first.)

On a non-legal note, you may still want to give attribution to yourself, since this makes it clear that nobody is being plagiarized.

Comment: Be careful however that if you also use *the question* in your post, you almost certainly have to respect the CC-by-SA terms for that text (unless you’re also the one who posted the question). I think it gets dicey if your answer has been edited by someone else. Using those edits in your Medium post (rather than your original test) requires attribution. To be honest, the simplest thing is to just include an attribution and ignore the fact that you could theoretically license your own content on different terms.

Comment: OP said, "I would use content that I have authored here" - so only talking about their own content.

Answer (score 17):

The answer given by Laurel is correct in that there is nothing preventing you from doing it. In fact, I've seen other sites often reproducing Q&A from various Stack Exchange sites (*How-To Geek* comes to mind), and heck, there are even a couple of guys who use tools to generate actual books and sell them. It's all allowed.

But since you ask about *"any written or unwritten rules or conventions"*, and this is Meta.SO, I would like to add my (mostly personal) view on this. I appreciate it may be unpopular.

Even in the case where the content is yours, in my opinion, this practice comes across as unnecessary, to say the least. The (presumably good) content is already on a platform that we all are familiar with; is accessible to everyone, can be easily found by search engines, etc. To simply reproduce it on a personal blogging or media service looks to me like someone who is seeking more attention than would be appropriate. To put it more bluntly, it looks... *weird*. Too pushy.

I know Stack Overflow and Medium are not comparable, and the latter gives you a more personal "touch" over the content you create. What I would definitely not see as unfavourable is if you only link to *some* of your great answers on Stack Overflow, not reproducing it, but instead using as a reference or starting point for a deeper analysis/educational experience. That's how I've seen [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/stackoverflow/) and others do it.

I mean all this respectfully.

Comment: _"It's all allowed"_ Yeah but if I ever ran into one of these people who takes my content and makes money out of it, with some half-assed attribution to SO in the small print to abide by the letter of the "law", you can be sure I will be letting them know what I think about it!

Comment: Oh me too. And I would demand a free copy of some books, if they were not terrible.

Comment: To me, it makes total sense to retain a copy of your best content on a platform you control. It could be part of your online branding, portfolio, etc. And you don't need to worry about other people editing it over time. I have no idea what you mean by "seeking more attention than would be appropriate" - what is the correct level of "attention" to seek on the internet, exactly?

Comment: @SteveBennett I'm afraid you might be reading too hard into that specific excerpt of my text. But overall I see the point of your argument.

Answer (score 1):

I would also consider keeping [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) (now a bit old, but still relevant) SO blog post in mind as you write your Medium articles. While I can appreciate that you intend to modify content into the form of an essay, I believe that step should not be optional. Otherwise there will be duplication of SO questions across sites without a mechanism to control that duplication.