# Citing an answer on Stack Exchange in an article

Tags: discussion

I used the answer by somebody in my article I published on the Internet. To be precise: the answer consists of the mathematical proof of a lemma that I posed as a question on Stack Exchange. Is it customary to cite the author or the answer in my article? Should I inform the author of the answer that his answer has been used in an article?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions

Comment: Stack Overflow material probably falls under some sort of open source license, so you likely would not be breaking any laws even if you did not cite.  But, that being said, on professional grounds, you absolutely _should_ cite that Stack article in your work.

Comment: See a recent [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386060/957731) here on a very similar question. Short answer: yes you can and yes you should cite the author.

Comment: @ivarni: My interpretation of that answer is that you have to cite (not optional) since the license is cc by-sa 3.0 **with attribution required**.

Comment: @BDL Yeah, I meant with *should* in the commanding fashion, not the suggestion one. Using *must* in this context would indeed be better, point taken.

Comment: You could probably use the [MLA style](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_works_cited_electronic_sources.html) of citing a comment and just say "Answer on" instead of "Comment on". If you prefer APA: [How to Cite Something You Found on a Website in APA Style](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/11/how-to-cite-something-you-found-on-a-website-in-apa-style.html?_ga=2.93843614.221428706.1560501466-1767006733.1560501466)

Comment: There's a [blog article about attribution linked at the bottom of every page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)...